# How to use Blogger API v3

Tags: c#, api, blogger

Here is the Blogger's API v3 page : https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using

and downloaded the NuGet Blogger API packages : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.blogger.v2

My developing environment is Visual Studio 2010 with C# language

How can i use the Blogger's API?

I just can't understand what they wrote in https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/blogger/v3/csharp/latest/namespaces.html ...

How to initialize a new Blogger Service and get a list of all the posts?

Where to auth with my application (the ClientID and ClientSecret)?

Answer (score 2):

You need GDATA client and for that you need to download Google API.
Download it [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/detail?name=Google_Data_API_Setup_2.2.0.0.msi&can=2&q=). You need to install that MSI and it will add dll, samples to your system.

> C:\Program Files\Google\Google Data API SDK

1. Add `Google.GData.Blogger.dll` to your project
2. After adding the reference, you can use this [link](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clients/cs/samples/blogger/ConsoleSample.cs) for reference.

Following code can be used for creating service and fetching data from Blogger.

```
Service service = new Service("blogger", "blogger-example");
string username = "abc@gmail.com";
string password = "abc143";
service.Credentials = new GDataCredentials(username, password);
```

Comment: @GaryNg: I doubt. What does it use then? I recently developed utility using API 3 and i definitely used Google.GData.Blogger.dll . AM i missing something here?

Comment: Your code is used for before last 10 months but it's now changed

Comment: OP asks to use an API KEY.

Answer (score 2):

This is a modern C# sample solution to access Blogger v3 API using an API KEY inside a console app.

Create a new .NET Framework console app project.

Install the following NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Blogger.v3/

Replace your Main code with the following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Blogger API Sample");
        Console.WriteLine("==================");

        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        System.Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            cts.Cancel();
        };

        try
        {
            MainAsync(args, cts.Token).Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        if (args == null || args.Length != 1) args = new string[] { "http://blogger.googleblog.com/" };

        // Create the service.
        BloggerService service = new BloggerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            ApplicationName = "Your Blogger App Name Here",
            ApiKey = "[YOUR_API_KEY_HERE]",
        });

        // Run the blog request.
        Console.WriteLine($"Executing blog {url} request...");
        var blogResult = await service.Blogs.GetByUrl(url).ExecuteAsync(ct);

        // Display the results.
        if (blogResult.Posts != null)
        {
            //Run the posts request
            Console.WriteLine($"Executing posts {blogResult.Posts.SelfLink} request...");
            var postsResult = await service.Posts.List(blogResult.Id).ExecuteAsync(ct);

            foreach (var post in postsResult.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{post.Id} - {post.Title}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Fist of all you have to install Blogger's API v3 from below link
you are installed for API V2

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Blogger.v3/

and there no code in https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/blogger/v3/csharp/latest/namespaces.html this link

Presently i am working on this, it's not coming..